# setting up Visual Studio for Windows beginner tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to learn Windows and c++ basics, and have downloaded Visual Studio for the first time, however I can't seem to figure out the proper setup for my needs.

I am trying to simply copy and paste the Windows beginner tutorial series(create window, open dialog box) from here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ff381399(en-us,VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ff381399%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx)

I simply can't figure out the proper project type, I'm expecting .cpp-s as .h-s and getting these windows markup .xaml-s and .cs-s.

Can somebody please drive me through in a couple lines what setup (mainly project type) should I use?

Comment: Why have you tagged C#?

Comment: I am trying to compile C++ code, but remove it, maybe mishuiding

Comment: You want to create a C++ "console project", and make sure that you select the "empty project" option.

Comment: @Sneftel thanks. Yeah, I tried that. The program.cs file contains a Main function wrapped in a namespace, however the tutorial is launching off with wWinMain, so somewhere deeper should be an implementation of default main. So what is this main function I get in the program.cs, and where should I put my wWinMain? What is my entry point?

Comment: actually, for that entry point you want a "windows application", not a "console application". Nevertheless, if you're seeing .cs files, you've created a C# project, not a C++ project. Try looking in "other project types", if you can't find it.

Comment: @Sneftel geez, I found it. Thanks, I think I would never have found other project options, if you did not mention them:)

Answer (score 1):

For the tutorial that you referenced the Project type you select at the File, New, Project menu command must be Visual C++, Win32, Win32 Project.